# Setting up the same route for both client and server using iron-router in meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to set up a route for POST requests, where the server does some logic and then the client loads a view *for the same route*. So, for example, my route `/myRoute` would have:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.route('/myRoute');
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Router.route('/myRoute', {where: 'server'})
    .post(function() {
      console.log('This is the server side');
      this.next();
    });
}
```

However, the server-side is not called at all, and I only get the template rendered with no console logs on the server.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You have a syntax error (forgot the closing brace of  the call to `post()`. I guess that this is just a typo, though. It is working for me using `wget --post-data="" http://localhost:3000/myRoute`.

Comment: Are you sure you want this to be a post request and not a GET request?

Comment: @MasterAM What do you mean working for you? For me, it ignores the server side part, OR claims there are no client routes when the server side is called.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Yep, pretty sure.

Comment: I setup a basic app with pretty much only your code in it (fixing the syntax error), used `wget` and `curl` to send a `post` requests and the `post` callback was triggered on the server and logged 'This is the server side'.

Comment: @MasterAM maybe I'm missing something. What are your meteor and iron-router versions?

Comment: meteor@1.1.9, 
meteor-base@1.0.1, 
iron:router@1.0.12